# Run web developer console in windows terminal

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, web-console

Is there any way to run the scripts which we run in the Developer console of Chrome or Firefox on Windows Terminal or CMD?

I want to run a Javascript code on every link I provide as input.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to use Nodejs and libraries such as cheerio, puppeteer or selenium, ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use node js its run your .js file in terminal and consoles  logs.
" node Yourfilename.js "
type this command in terminal and hit enter your file will run on terminal

Comment: This will run the code in my terminal, but that code is for automating button clicks. How can I refer to the document of a website here?